# What makes some diode surge rated higher than others?

Tags: current, surge

The title explains it all. How various diodes can be assigned distinct surge current ratings? I understand that higher current implies greater power dissipation (don't know if its true for diode but true for resistors), leading to potential diode breakdown at a specific temperature threshold?

I am looking at the LL4148 diode with a maximum surge current of 2 A:
[image]
and S1MFL series with max current of 30 A:
[image]

Any helps would be much appreciated.

Comment: Substrate defects, and area, I believe, of both silicon and wire bonding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can classify component heating into two extremes.

1 ) Long term
2 ) Pulse

1 ) Long term heating is limited by the thermal resistance from the junction to the leads and body of the device, and ultimately to ambient. This is also called isothermal - the component stays at a constant high temperature.

2 ) Pulse heating happens so fast that the body of the component stays cold, and only the semiconductor junction heats up, with no time for the heat to spread into the contact areas, the leads or the body. This is also called adiabatic heating. The more mass there is in the junction itself, and the more uniform the heat-producing part of the junction is, the more energy it can absorb before it reaches a damaging temperature.

Of course, real life falls somewhere between the two extremes, and many data sheets have graphs for how the component handles 'long pulses' as well, where some of the body starts to absorb heat.

In a diode designed to tolerate surges, the junction will be big, and uniform. It might still be packaged in a small outline, with a low long term current handling. While the two ratings are not totally independent, there is scope to make a device that emphasises one or the other rating.

A couple of examples are the 1N400x and 1N540x families, with 1 A continuous 30 A surge, and 3 A continuous 200 A surge ratings respectively.

Do read the datasheet carefully about the surge rating. The rating will be highest for a single pulse, starting with the junction at a low temperature, usually 25 C. This is quite realistic for a rectifier diode, which will be charging up its power supply capacitors only on equipment switch-on, so once and from cold. The time duration often matches a half cycle of mains waveform for just this application. There will generally be a lower rating for 'repetitive pulses', especially if the junction starts from hot.

Answer (score 5):

To add onto [Neil's excellent answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/689504/311631), I'd just like to add some specifics:

- Short time scales, on the order of ~µs, take place within the die;
- ~ms, heat is transitioning from die, through die attach (solder/epoxy) to mounting base;
- ~100s ms, from package to heatsink or leads;
- ~100s s, from heatsink and PCB to ambient.

Thus we can identify the 1µs test case as a die property (LL4148 is a little signal diode), and 8.3ms as involving more of the diode package (S1MFL is a SOD−123FL, a larger chip sandwiched between flat metal tabs of the lead frame).

In general, energy of the pulse increases as duration increases, while peak power decreases.  The exact rate of this increase/decrease depends on the materials and geometry the device is made of, but very roughly speaking, generally goes as \$E \sim \sqrt{t}\$ and \$P \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\$.  (There will always be a factor of \$t\$ between these, because energy is the integral of power.)

Because it depends on geometry, it is not safe to extrapolate to wildly different time scales; it is safer for example to assume the LL4148 is *at least* 1A peak for 8.3ms, but how much more, you don't know.  (To be sure, it's less than 2A, proving the point.)

As for why 8.3ms (60Hz half cycle), or anything else; the LL4148 is sold as a signal diode not a rectifier, so it's probably not very important what current it can handle over a mains cycle, but a momentary overload rating (1s pulse) may be handy.  Conversely, the S1MFL is very likely to be used to charge a capacitor from mains supply, so the 8.3ms pulse is useful to know.

When transient thermal impedance is given, the \$E\$ and \$P\$ pulse scaling can be calculated from it.

Comment: In fact, the test waveforms used for 8.3 ms overload ratings are frequently an actual half-sine (or quarter-sine) in shape, too. Meanwhile the non-Americans have to just hope that an additional 1.7 ms doesn't cause any issues if they just derate by an arbitrary fudge factor....

Comment: Yes, it's also a half-sine, while most other pulses are square unless noted otherwise. (Except TVS, where it's a surge waveform unless noted otherwise; but they do usually note what waveform was used.) I have seen 50Hz half-sine in datasheets before; woe be unto USA (and half JP) engineers. :^)

Comment: Well, US engineers can be sure that something that can handle a 10 ms half-sine pulse of a certain current can definitely also handle an 8.3 ms half-sine of the same current!